# Multiple css changes on only single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have to do multiple css changes on different classes on specific url only page not all. Like 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksvfa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add specific css for specific page, Please add the below code in your current theme **functions.php** file .

```
add_action('wp_head','add_css_specific_page');
function add_css_specific_page(){
    //In wordpress to get your specific page id inspect in browser and see into body class
    if(is_page('YOUR_PAGE_ID')){
     ?>
       <style>
        /* pase your css code here */
        p{
         font-size:12px;
        }
       </style>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use # sign before id, Instead use like is_page('6403')

Comment: are you working on page or post . These are two different post type. If you are working on post then is_page condition will not work. Can you paste here class name which apply on body tag.

Comment: page-template-default page page-id-6403 logged-in admin-bar theme-amely woocommerce-cart woocommerce-page woocommerce-js site-header-menu-bottom wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-6.1 vc_responsive customize-support

Comment: The above code will definitely work. please change is_page() condition with is_cart(). I Hope it will help you. Please also check have you paste the code in your current theme functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this in CSS directly,

but the solution is to wrap this page with **class** it's like **NameSpace** & all templates do this

```
.shopping-cart-page p {
}

.shopping-cart-page .total-price {
}
```

and in HTML put

```
<div class="shopping-cart-page">
    ....
</div>
```